# How can I authenticate users in my app with Firebase Authentication

Tags: python, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, kivy

I have a `Python` app (using `Kivy`). At the start of the app there is a login screen, currently it takes anything as input and allows users to pass, but I want that it only lets them pass if the username is registered and the password is correct. I know that I can do this with Firebase Authentication but can't find out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Firebase does have an SDK for Python, that is an Admin SDK that is meant for use in trusted environments - and it doesn't have any way to sign a user in.

The only alternative I can think of is to sign in the user by calling the [REST API for Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth). You'll specifically want to look at the methods for [signing up a user with email+password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password) and then [signing them in with those](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password).

If you're new to this, a quick [search on 'firebase authentication python rest'](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+authentication+python+rest) also shows promising results.